# switching tabs on button click in wpf

Tags: wpf, tabs

I have 4 tabs and clicking the button move to front it should change tabs the next one. But out of the four tabs, tab 2 is hidden and I dont want it to show. So if the screen is at tab 1, on move forward it should display tab 3 and from tab 3 it should open tab 4. Similarly on move back if it's at tab 3, it should go to tab 1 without displaying tab 2. I tried this implementation but it still goes to tab 2.

```
        private void movefront_click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (tabIUWM.SelectedIndex == 2)
        {
            TabStudyAreaInterface.Visibility = Visibility.Visible; //tabstudyareainterface is the name of tab 2
        }
        else
        {
            tabIUWM.SelectedIndex = tabIUWM.SelectedIndex + 1;
        }        

    }
    private void moveback_click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        if (tabIUWM.SelectedIndex == 2)
        {
            TabStudyAreaInterface.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;

        }
        else
        {

            tabIUWM.SelectedIndex = tabIUWM.SelectedIndex - 1;
        }

        if (tabIUWM.SelectedIndex == -1)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("This is the beginning screen");
        }

    }
```

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

In the following solution [extension methods](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx) have been added to the [TabControl](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.tabcontrol(v=vs.110).aspx) class that handle navigating back and forth between [TabItem](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.tabitem(v=vs.110).aspx) elements. These methods can be called in your click events. All items that are in the TabControl that are Hidden/Collapsed will be ignored.

**MainWindow.cs**

```
private void OnPrevClick( object sender, RoutedEventArgs e )
{
    TabControl.PrevVisibleTab();
}

private void OnNextClick( object sender, RoutedEventArgs e )
{
    TabControl.NextVisibleTab();
}
```

**TabControlExtensions.cs**

```
internal static class TabControlExtensions
{
    public static void PrevVisibleTab( this TabControl tabControl )
    {
        var visibleTabs = tabControl.Items
            .OfType<TabItem>()
            .Where( t => t.Visibility == Visibility.Visible )
            .ToList();

        if( tabControl.SelectedItem == null )
        {
            tabControl.SelectedItem = visibleTabs.LastOrDefault();
            return;
        }

        if( !visibleTabs.Contains( tabControl.SelectedItem ) )
        {
            tabControl.SelectedItem = null;
            return;
        }

        int index = visibleTabs.IndexOf( tabControl.SelectedItem as TabItem ) - 1;
        if( index < 0 ) index += visibleTabs.Count;

        tabControl.SelectedItem = visibleTabs[index];
    }

    public static void NextVisibleTab( this TabControl tabControl )
    {
        var visibleTabs = tabControl.Items
            .OfType<TabItem>()
            .Where( t => t.Visibility == Visibility.Visible )
            .ToList();

        if( tabControl.SelectedItem == null )
        {
            tabControl.SelectedItem = visibleTabs.FirstOrDefault();
            return;
        }

        if( !visibleTabs.Contains( tabControl.SelectedItem ) )
        {
            tabControl.SelectedItem = null;
            return;
        }

        int index = ( visibleTabs.IndexOf( tabControl.SelectedItem as TabItem ) + 1 ) % visibleTabs.Count;

        tabControl.SelectedItem = visibleTabs[index];
    }
}
```

Comment: Avoid using TabControl.PrevVisibleTab() as is. Use YOUR x:Name="TabName" instead. TabName.PrevVisibleTab() works